# Setting aspNetCompatibility Enabled in wcf screwing anonymous access

Tags: wcf

I have given anonymous access to my service. And I m able to access with out establishing credentials.
I wanted to make use session in wcf service, for this I m trying to use aspNetCompatibility Enabled to true in system.serviceModel. When I included this line, it is redirecting me to login page whenever I m requesting service.svc file. Any guess as to why it aspNetCompatibility Enabled overriding access policy? What should I do to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Once the aspNetCompatibilityEnabled is true, the ASP.NET pipeline comes into the play and its authentication and authorization is dome. Check the system.web/authorization section in the web.config. Do you have deny users? If so, remove it. you may also try to add

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Add a simple aspx page in the same web application and check if you can get to that page without being authenticated. If not, there is somewhere authentication/authorization requirement in the web app. You can set location based exclusion list but if the above doesn't work, that won't work either. Do you mind showing the web.config (mask out anything sensitive)?